# Why is IOption parameter value null when it has been configured in the Startup.cs file

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, nullreferenceexception

I have configured my `Settings` object in my `StartUp.cs` file, however when i pass IOption to a class, i get null reference exception when getting the connetion string.

**StartUp.cs**

```
        services.Configure<MongoDbSettings>(option =>
        {
            option.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings.ConnectionString").Value;
            option.Database = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings.Database").Value;
        });
```

**Actual class**

public class BlogPostContext : IBlogPostContext
{
    public IMongoDatabase MongoDatabase { get; }

```
public IMongoCollection<BlogPost> BlogPostModelCollection =>
    MongoDatabase.GetCollection<BlogPost>("BlogPost");

public BlogPostContext(IOptions<MongoDbSettings> settings)
{
    var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
    MongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.Database);
}
```

}

my exception is on this line

```
var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);
```

which is a null reference exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, a single character error. Instead of

```
    services.Configure<MongoDbSettings>(option =>
    {
        option.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings.ConnectionString").Value;
        option.Database = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings.Database").Value;
    });
```

I used:

```
    services.Configure<MongoDbSettings>(option =>
    {
        option.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings:ConnectionString").Value;
        option.Database = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings:Database").Value;
    });
```

I didnt realise  i was using a period instead of a colon